# Remove double quotes from a Table Name using SEQUELIZE Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have created an Account table in the PostgreSQL database using SEQUELIZE in Nodejs. I have used npx commands to create the tables.

```
$ npx sequelize db:create
$ npx sequelize db:migrate
```

By default, the table is created with double-quotes. For example, If I want to check the entries in the Account table, the sql command is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM "Account";
```

I want to remove the double-quotes from the table name i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM Account;
```

In [Sequelize Manual](http://www.nodeclass.com/api/sequelize.html), I have found an option (options.quoteIdentifiers) which states that "Set to false to make table names and attributes case-insensitive on Postgres and skip double quoting of them."

When I applied this option in my code, still the Account table is created with double-quotes. I am not sure whether I commit any mistake. Please check my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  options.quoteIdentifiers = false, 
  {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
},
);
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Account = sequelize.define('Account', {
    epprojectname: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    projectid: DataTypes.STRING,
    vendorparameters: DataTypes.STRING,
    credentials: DataTypes.STRING,
    author: DataTypes.STRING,
    localnumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    loginid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
  },
  );
```

Comment: `[options.quoteIdentifiers=true]` is used for case-insensative which means `"Account"` & `"account"` is same it'll not solve your issue .please share your database schema where table is created with `" "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used "=" instead of ":". You can replace the equal sign with colon and try again

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,
  quoteIdentifiers: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and the solution is model name using table name, define freezeTableName (true) and schema on model option

for example my table name with schema is **keranjang.user** and the model look like:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
username: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true
},
password: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
}
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  schema: 'keranjang'
})
```